# how can i convert my binary data to textual data

Tags: matlab

Here is a string-to-binary conversion program.

```
str='haseeb'

int16bStr = uint16(str);

typecast(int16bStr,'uint8');

a=dec2bin(int16bStr)
```

I'm using this code to convert the text "haseeb" into binary form:

```
str =

haseeb
```

```
a =

1101000
1100001
1110011
1100101
1100101
1100010
```

I want to convert this binary output of "a" back to text (i.e. "haseeb"). I am using Matlab r2009b.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dec2bin.html - look for clues...

Comment: Look at see also on matworks help. If you look there a function bin2dec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this :

```
word = reshape(char(bin2dec(a)),1,[])
```

And you can skip your typecast just by doing

```
int8bStr = uint8(str);
```